# Поиск неиспользуемых функций и переменых в коде

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Собственно есть легаси код, который частично переписывается, обновляется.
Как и чем можо проводить поиск в коде неиспользуемых переменных, функций, классов, файлов и т.д.
Дело под виндой, студия 1998, 2017

Интересует реальный опыт в решении подобного плана задач и использования того или иного инструментария 
(из большинства маркетинговых статей или обзоров абсолютно неясо насколько тот или иной инструмент работает)

Схожие вопросы по теме:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380153/finding-dead-code-in-a-large-c-legacy-application
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Comment: так вы же в вопросе сами привели ссылки на вопросы по теме... Почему ваш вопрос не является дубликатом?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в вопросах нету прямых овтетов, только ощий обзор функционала, понимаю, что вопрос так себе, но вдруг кто-то даст мне искомый "золотой молоток"

Comment: Обычно хватает предупреждений компилятора, Wunused и аналоги.

Comment: @user7860670 всегда хватает)))

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте предупреждения компилятора, там выводится информация о неиспользованных переменных. Ещё в Visual Studio есть поиск, можно посмотреть, где используется название функции/класса, кроме объявления и определения.